# Issue with object assignment -- Why is Sheets([SheetName]) not working?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy/paste from one worksheet within a workbook to another worksheet within the same workbook. I am having a very frustrating problem with the following error while trying to assign my ranges:

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

```
Dim c As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Range
Dim tgt As Range

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet 1")

Set c = ws1.Range("Named_Range").Cells(1, 1)
Set tgt = ws1.Range(c, c.Cells(10, 1)) 'Purpose is to create a range with the first 10 cells of Named_Range, but I need it to be dynamic

'To test that range is being assigned correctly
tgt.Select
```

At this point I get the error code referenced above. However, the code runs provided that I add

```
ws1.Select
```

above "Set c = ..."

Any idea what's going on? [My understanding is that using 'Select' in this way is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/12189892), and I don't want to be messing around with selecting particular Sheets anyway because I am trying to eventually toggle between them while copy/pasting.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Worksheet` is different than `Range`, `ws1` should be a defined as a `Worksheet`.
2. The named range cannot have spaces in its name. This works:

---

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Range
    Dim tgt As Range

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet 1")
    Set c = ws1.Range("Named_Range_A").Cells(1, 1)
    Set tgt = ws1.Range(c, c.Cells(10, 1))

    Debug.Print tgt.Address

End Sub
```

As additional bonus - `Worksheet` is a different object than `Sheet`, you may consider using `Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet 1")`. The `Sheet` object be either `Worksheet` or `Chart`, thus being a bit more explicit could be nice.

Comment: @FaneDuru - I guess you are missing something, the `c.Cells(10,1)` defines the low right cell of the `tgt` range.

Comment: I mistakenly showed ```Dim ws1 As Range``` ... didn't make that mistake in the actual code. I also do have underscores in my actual named range. Apologies for the errors on my part, I've edited the post.

Comment: @bhbennett3 - that's strange, I was able to run your code, simply adding `Sub TestMe` on the top and adding the named range. Are you sure the named range is in `Sheet 1` or in another sheet?

Comment: It is... I've used your method - ```Debug.Print tgt.Address``` - and confirmed that my ranges actually are assigning correctly. I think the error may actually be due to something else in the module. Bad question on my part, thank you for your help though.